# Could forgot work in my example

Tags: past-tense

I **had forgotten** to copy this message but your phone call reminded me to do it today.

Could I use forgot here. I don't think so because the phone call reminded me to do it (the action of forgotten is completed) . Because of the phone call I remembered I had to copy the message so the forgetting was finished

Comment: "I forgot to copy this message but your phone call reminded me to do it" is fine, so is "I had forgotten to copy this message, but your phone call reminded me to do it". Unfortunately... I don't really know why...

Answer (score 1):

You could use either simple past ("I forgot") or past perfect ("I had forgotten.")

The past perfect is okay because it's a way to talk about two different points in the past. For a simpler example:

> I had just left my house when I met you.

Both events here are in the past—leaving the house and meeting the person. We use simple past for "met" and past perfect for "had left" to show that the leaving happened earlier than the meeting.

Many sources talk about "completion," [like this one](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect/): "The past perfect, also called the pluperfect, is a verb tense used to talk about actions that were completed before some point in the past." But you don't have to get too philosophical about whether the forgetting or the remembering were really a state that was fully "completed," or how they affected each other. The point of this direction is that, if you had a point in the past, and another thing that was true before that point *but also true at that point*, the past perfect is not the right choice. But often, we can use the past perfect to talk *about a moment* even if the effects of that moment continued. For instance:

> The store had opened before we got there.

Of course, the store still *was* open when we got there, but the moment of opening was in the past.

In your example, "you forgot." On its own, that simple verb talks about a moment of ceasing to remember. Maybe you *continued* in a state of not-remembering, but we can still use the past perfect, "I **had forgotten**, but your phone call reminded me," because the moment of forgetting was earlier than the moment of reminding.

---

Most constructions that *can* use the past perfect *can* also use the simple past.

> **I forgot** to copy this message but your phone call reminded me to do it today.

This works perfectly well, since "forgot" can speak of a moment in time. We aren't confused about which thing happened first, even without the past perfect, because the events make it obvious.

The simpler example I gave earlier doesn't work quite as well:

> I left my house when I met you.

This is grammatically perfectly okay, and chances are the context would still keep it clear, but on its own this becomes less clear about the sequence. Did I leave my house *just when* I met you? Maybe *because* I met you?

But the other example,

> The store opened before we got there.

Is perfectly clear in the simple past, mostly because the sentence clearly talks about the order of events.

So, to sum up:

- Past perfect can be a great way to make sequence of events clear
- You don't always *have* to use it; many sentences can be clear even if using only simple past, but
- You might as well use it when you can.

Comment: "I wasn't expecting you to contact me again!! I  tried to contact you so many times and did not receive an answer that I had completely forgotten that I had made an order.I was surprised to receive your email today  .    Could I write forgot  because the forgetting happened after not receiving the answer so the order is clear .  There is no need to use past perfect unless you want to emphasize that the forgetting is completed (  if I follow your logic )

Comment: @user5577 Yes, *in this case* you could use "forgot" without it being confusing. Though in other cases you might *have* to use past perfect to avoid confusion. And in this case, you *can* use past perfect and it helps make it clear.