# Should I use past perfect here

Tags: past-tense

> I was very happy and surprised after I opened your parcel because inside was  a copy of the "Paperniks" single. In your last email  you **wrote** that it was sold out.

Do we understand that the last email happened before I was happy and surprised or would it be better to leave the ambiguity to use past perfect. It is not obvious that the last email occurred before my surprise. I think it is clearer with past perfect but both tenses seem good. What do you think about it?

Comment: I'm leaving this open because although the question sounds like it might be a request for proofreading, it's clearly "*focused on **something in particular***" --in this case particular verb tenses-- rather than a request for "***finding and correcting errors** or **improving the phrasing***", as the close note says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a repeat of [your last question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309725/could-forgot-work-in-my-example) in some ways. Yes, past perfect is a good choice here. No, past simple is not confusing because the context explains (you were happy and surprised because you hadn't expected to get it; I disagree with you and would say it *is* obvious that the email came before the surprise). So you *could* use simple past, but why not use past perfect?

Note, I wouldn't say "I was very happy and surprised **after** I opened your parcel"; I would probably say "**when**." It's true that one might say that opening it is the moment in which you cut the tape and open the box, and that the surprise came a moment later, but "opening a box" can refer to the entire process, and those two moments are very close together in time.

Comment: Strictly speaking about meaning what does the past perfect add to it? the connection is obvious ?

Comment: In this case it adds nothing, since the order *is* obvious. In some other example, in which the order were *not* obvious... it would save the day!

Comment: @AndyBonner I applaud your distinction between the use of **after** and **when**. It's a bugbear of mine to hear the constant lazy use of **after** on the media, as in:  **10 people were killed after the plane crashed.** I always want to ask the writer **how long after?**